# I want replace He with She with php regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

I am using below code to replace he with she and him with her.

```
 $string = 'The quick he fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
  $patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/he/';
//$patterns[1] = '/brown/';
//$patterns[2] = '/fox/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'she';
//$replacements[1] = 'black';
//$replacements[0] = 'slow';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

But it's returning following string after execution

```
Tshe quick she fox jumps over tshe lazy dog.
```

So the issue is it's also converting **"the" with "tshe"** I want to only replace words that are separate words **(Like He)** instead of part of words
**(not like the).**

Comment: Have you tried with space ? like `$patterns[0] = '/ he /';`

Comment: Better yet `'/\bhe\b/'`

Comment: no,  make sense man.Let me try

Comment: thanks man it's working by adding space @HimanshuUpadhyay

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried with space ? like `$patterns[0] = '/ he /';`

This is your solution.

Comment: Thank you @Zedd Index for accepting my answer.

Comment: With this approach a regex is not needed, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php would suffice. This won't match all instances though.

Answer (score 4):

Try this: This will replace the whole word only

If `$string` contains UTF-8 text, you'll have to add the Unicode modifier "u", so that non-latin characters are not misinterpreted as word boundaries:

```
$string = 'The quick he fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

$replace = preg_replace('/\bhe\b/u', 'she', $string);

echo  $replace;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `/\bshe\b/`

```
<?php
$string = "The quick he-fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
echo preg_replace("/\bhe(-?)\b/u", "she$1", $string);
?>
```

The `/u` modifier is for unicode support, to ensure that non-Unicode characters are interpreted correctly.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8XdrH)

This will match `he fox` and also `he-fox` and change it to the required `she fox` or `she-fox`.

#### Explanation

- `\b` - Start word boundary.
- `he` - Matches the literal word `he`.
- `(` - Begin the capture group.
- `-?` - Matches zero or one literal hyphen.
- `\b` - End word boundary.

In the replacement, the `"she$1`" will write the word `she` and the `$1` will be the capture of the group. If there is a hyphen it will output it, otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spaces:

```
$patterns[0] = '/[\s]he[\s]/';
```

You can test your regular expressions here:

https://regex101.com/